# Remote assistance for Macs

Tags: remote-desktop

What is currently the best remote assistance/remote desktop application for Macs?  I think unattended access (no remote user needed) and file transfer would be useful.  Teamviewer seems to fit the bill, but I am not a Mac guy so I was wondering if there were other/better options for the Mac.

Comment: Over internet or just your LAN?

Comment: over the internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use TeamViewer since years.

From Mac - to PC or Mac.

From USA to Europe.

Comment: Well it looks like TeamViewer is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Apple Remote Desktop](https://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/features.html).

> Apple Remote Desktop is the best way to manage the Mac computers on your network. Distribute software, provide real-time online help to end users, create detailed software and hardware reports, and automate routine management tasks—all without leaving your desk. Featuring Automator actions and Remote Spotlight search, Apple Remote Desktop makes your job easier than ever.

Power Copy:
The file-copy engine in Apple Remote Desktop supports 64-bit file sizes, network bandwidth limits, and optional encryption of data streams.